# awk/bash: adding column to file repeatedly

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I have a little data-manipulation problem which surely can be solved by using `awk` or `bash`.

I have two existing data-files. 
The first consists of tab-separated fields which are arranged in n number of blocks. Each block is separated by a single blank line.

```
1  3
2  4
3  5

4  6
5  7
6  8
```

The second file only has one column of data which is as long as every block in the first file.

```
a
b
c
```

My problem is that I have to append the data-column in file two to every block in file one, such that the output would look like:

```
1  3  a
2  4  b
3  5  c

4  6  a
5  7  b
6  8  c
```

Do you have any idea? I already tried to write the data of file two n-times (the number of blocks) in a new file and append this with `awk` but I didn't get this working properly.

Answer (score 2):

This simple, dynamic one liner will do the trick:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[i++]=$0;next}{print (NF?$0 OFS a[j++%i]:$0)}' OFS='\t' file2 file1
1   3   a
2   4   b 
3   5   c

4   6   a
5   7   b
6   8   c
```

Answer (score 1):

Save each line of second file in an array and use module operator (`%`) to cycle about its content for each line of first file with data:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } 
    FNR == NR { data[ NR - 1 ] = $0; next } 
    ! $0 { print; next } 
    { ++i; print $0, data[ (i - 1) % 3 ] }
' file2 file1
```

It yields:

```
1  3    a
2  4    b
3  5    c

4  6    a
5  7    b
6  8    c
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two file, `a.dat`, `b.dat`, you can do this

```
cat -n a.dat > aa.dat
cat -n b.dat > bb.dat
join aa.dat bb.dat | awk '{$1=""}1' > c.dat
rm aa.dat bb.dat
```

you result is saved in `c.dat`. `awk '{$1=""}1'` removes the first column which is the line number.